# How does connected mode work for public projects?

Tags: sonarlint, sonarcloud

I have a public GitHub project I’m scanning with SonarCloud. I also use the VS Code SonarLint plugin in connected mode with a user token I generated for myself.

This project is public and visible to everyone.

Are users able to generate their own tokens for their own SonarCloud accounts and use connected mode for my public project? I’m obviously not going to generate user tokens for all public contributors. I couldn't find docs pertaining to authenticating to public projects with your own user account for IDE integrations like this.